# Set element width to 100% scrollable width

Tags: html, css

I am facing a layout issue with CSS where I cannot set an element attribute to the *maximum scrollable* width. In my situation, I have a relative sized div (in real code, it is supposed to be responsive) showing text inside. The objective is to set a background color to *some* lines in order to underline difference.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 25%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
span {
  white-space: pre;
  /* required */
  font-family: monospace;
  /* required */
  display: block;
  /* required to make width effective */
  width: 100%;
}
.green {
  background-color: #7f7;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <span class="green">   That's an add ! Scroll me...
    </span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablablablablablabl
    </span>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvb25pt9/) I made to illustrate.

I cannot set the background color to the end of the block, which means that if someone scroll, he will not see the color.

There are several questions like that on Stackoverflow and many suggest using a `min-width` value (i.e.  [background css 100% width horizontal scroll issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565422/background-css-100-width-horizontal-scroll-issue)). Thing is it is not that good if the content does not reach the `min-width` value.

If there is a proper way to fix this, I would be glad to hear it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vw (100% viewport width)` to stretch the container to the end of viewport. You also need to change your `display` to `table-header-group:`

```
span {
  white-space: pre;  /* required */
  font-family: monospace;  /* required */
  display: table-header-group;  /* required to make width effective */
  width: 100vw; /*100% of viewport width*/
}
```

`vh` (viewport height) can also be used in cases you need to stretch the container to 100% of viewport height.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to use a display:block for it. You changed the display for block to inline-block for some reason in your new JSFiddle. Use display:block; instead

Comment: ok got it. Use display:table-header-group instead. it should work fine

Comment: I am updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for your deep search ;) Works like a charm!